# What's the Ruby equivalent for "php://input"?

Tags: php, ruby, silverlight

I have created a very simple PHP file that does very simple job, it streams the images from a Silverlight OutOfBrowser application to the server, it mixes between `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables, matter of fact here is my very simple code, I am aware of its lack of security but I wrote it anyway just to make sure I can write files over the network and it worked 100% with multiple files uploaded etc.

```
<?php
 //Gets 
  $myFile = $_GET['FileName'] ? $_GET['FileName'] : "input_stream.txt";
  $openedFile = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");  
  $input = file_get_contents("php://input");            
  fwrite($openedFile, $input);
  fclose($openedFile);

  //Check the mime type of the file (WRONG WAY)
  $mimeType = mime_content_type($myFile);   
  $input = null;    
  $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
  $mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $myFile);
  echo $myFile . 'was uploaded, mime type : ' . $mimeType;
?>
```

So is there any simple Ruby alternative to get the raw POST data (which will be a ByteArray from Silverlight)?

Comment: `STDIN`?  I'm thinking Ruby has more direct access to standard input than PHP does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use a gem for http access. Here's one:

https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

This example looks like what you need:

https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/basic.rb

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Rails 3, request.raw_post() is what you are looking for. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-raw_post

Comment: i'm away from the project right now, i'll try and let you know, thanks, but it seems like it is what i am looking for -judging by the method name-.